# Shoulda-matchers not working for PORO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

So I have the following spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

class SpecRecord
  # include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :email
  validates :email, rfc_compliant: true
end

describe RfcCompliantValidator do
  subject { SpecRecord.new }

   it { is_expected.to allow_value('test@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to allow_value('disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to allow_value('other.email-with-dash@example.net').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to allow_value('x@example.org').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to allow_value('test@example.123-online.tv').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to allow_value("0123456789#!$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org.co.uk").for(:email) }

   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('john316').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('test@example..com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('this\ still\"not\\allowed@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('test@ex:amp,le.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('t:est@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('te,st@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('te()st@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('te[]st@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('te<>st@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value('te"st@example.com').for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value("test@exampledotcom").for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value("testexample").for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value("test@example.com123").for(:email) }
   it { is_expected.to_not allow_value("78901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901212+x@example.com").for(:email) }
 end
```

In `rails_helper` I have the following defined:

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    # Choose a test framework:
    with.test_framework :rspec

    # Choose one or more libraries:
    # with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
    with.library :action_controller
    # Or, choose the following (which implies all of the above):
    # with.library :rails
  end
end
```

In my other tests that leverage allow_value, the tests seem to be working, but for some reason `allow_value` isn't found here. Any thoughts?

Comment: @engineersmnky that was it! Had just discovered it myself and hadn't posted an answer yet. But in any case, where you posted first, if you want to post your answer, I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`allow_value`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb) is part of the `Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel` module for scoping purposes.

Whether or not this module is including in the tested scope is determined by whether or not the object being tested is marked as a `:model` object via the option `type` passed to the describe block.[Source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/integrations/libraries/active_model.rb#L12) and [Source for RSpec configuration](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/integrations/test_frameworks/rspec.rb#L12)

since your spec does not mark `RfcCompliantValidator` as a `:model` these methods are not included in the testing scope.

To resolve this all you need to do is mark it as such

```
describe RfcCompliantValidator, type: :model do 
   ###
```

and the `AllowValueMatcher` will be available in your tests.